# Not able to run globally installed node packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, httpserver

I have nodejs in my system. And I installed "http-server" globally using npm( npm install -g http-server). After installing http-server I tried to run http-server, but it is showing "'http-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I have added `"%AppData%\Roaming\npm;"` in `NODE_PATH` and `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\;/usr/local/share/npm/bin/;"` in `PATH`. But still I have the same issue.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Try, `export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Did you use "npm install -g http-server" ?

Comment: Try `%AppData%\Roaming\npm\node_modules;` in NODE_PATH

Comment: @Manwal I have tried that too.

Comment: @david-r I didnt get that sir.

Comment: @hurricane yes. I have used npm install -g http-server

Comment: @Anna You need to execute that command in your bash terminal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open command prompt and do following :

1. **npm config get prefix** 
   And append the output of above command to PATH for example:

> o/p C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm

2. **Do as set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm**

Comment: I did all this and then I tried 'http-server', its working.  But then I closed the command prompt window and I have opened a new window and tried to run 'http-server', it again showing the same error.

Comment: Then It may be admin issue of your system. Other wise i faced same issue, but using this my problem got resolved

Comment: Works like a charm but set PATH command didn't work for me, had to add the path manually.

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
export PATH="$(yarn global bin):$PATH"
```

Read more [here](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global/#adding-the-install-location-to-your-path)